# OO - Technique for separating objects from instances without introducing bad naming conventions

Tags: oop

Often times I need to create an encapsulation to hold an array of an Entity.  Let's say we have a class that represents an HTML table.

```
public class Tables
{
   public Table[] Tables;
   public Tables(){}
}
public class Table
{
   public Header Header;
   public Row Row;
   public Footer Footer;
   public Table(){} 
}
```

Here, my `Tables` encapsulate a Collection of `Table`.  I want to call my Table[] Object `Tables`, but this clashes with my Encapsulation.  To me, both represent a table.  How should I fix my naming?

Secondly, my Table contains a Footer

```
//A Special type of Row in a Table
public class Footer: Row
{
}
```

I could solve this by making my Members lower cased.  Although, this goes against Microsoft recommended practices for public members.

I could append a `Obj` to my Member names...once again, not a good practice.  Perhaps I'm viewing my OO encapsulations incorrectly.

Comment: Why do you have a full class just to store an array of objects(Tables)? I understand you said that "often I need to", but this doesn't seem like something you would ever need to do.

Comment: Perhaps there are (or will be) more things in it. I don't think this sort of class is very uncommon in OOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be as descriptive as possible in your naming.  What is the feature of your `Tables` class that requires a new class rather than just an array?  If there isn't anything then just use an array, otherwise include the distinctive feature of your class in the name.

Comment: Tables is intended to be more of a future proof.  When/if a unique behavior/attribute of a Table collection arises, the consumers will already have Tables collections available to them.  For now, yes an array will work.  Though, this doesn't answer problem #2.

Comment: If that's the case then I would just go with @Legogris and just name it TableCollection.  Also, you probably should just name your `Tables` array `items` or some such.  It's already apparent what type it is from the class name.  Generally speaking, I would avoid "future proofing" something if I didn't actually know of any cases where it would be needed since it just adds complexity where it isn't needed.

Comment: Before "future proofing" your code, please read this first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it

Answer (score 1):

"Here, my Tables encapsulate a Collection of Table."

Why not call your class just that - TableCollection?

Answer (score 0):

Use generics/templates/whatever it is called in your language:

`List<Table>`
   `ArrayList<Table>`
   `Collection<Table>`

If you need a custom method *on* your collection class (i.e. call through `this`), you are doing it wrong.